# Looping through dynamic sheet names

Tags: vba, excel

I am looping through a bunch of files in my folder and trying to copy a static column and paste to a master sheet. However every sheet I am looping through is a different name.

I believe this part of the code has to be changed:

```
xlsFiles.Sheets("Sheet3").Columns("20").Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r).Offset(1, 0).
```

What can I use in place of sheets("Sheet3") ?

Here is the full code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim wsMaster As Workbook, csvFiles As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim File As Integer
Dim r As Long

Public Sub Consolidate()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Select files to process"
        .Show

        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

        Set wsMaster = ActiveWorkbook

        For File = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count

            Filename = .SelectedItems.Item(File)


           If Right(Filename, 5) = ".csv*" Then
    Set csvFiles = Workbooks.Open(Filename, 0, True)
    r = wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    csvFiles.Sheets(1).Columns("col name").Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r).Offset(1, 0)
    csvFiles.Close SaveChanges:=False 'close without saving
            End If


        Next File 'go to the next file and repeat the process

    End With

    Set wsMaster = Nothing
    Set csvFiles = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use Sheets(3) instead of Sheets("Sheet3") if the sheet's index is always 3 i.t. it's position in the workbook.

Comment: thanks..dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you already got by @sktneer in the comments above.

You could shorten and "clean-up" your `If` section code a little, try the code below:

```
If Right(Filename, 5) = ".xls*" Then
    Set xlsFiles = Workbooks.Open(Filename, 0, True)
    r = wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    xlsFiles.Sheets(3).Columns("20").Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r).Offset(1, 0)
    xlsFiles.Close SaveChanges:=False 'close without saving
End If
```

Comment: having trouble with it now lol, ill update my code. Not sure why I need file name , but I am looping through csv files, ill show you updated code above.

Comment: @Jonnyboi in your edited code above how does `Filename` gets it's String value ? where is the part `=SelectedItem`

Comment: added back the selected item, accidentally got rid of it. but for some reason im not getting any copying into my master sheet

Comment: @Jonnyboi if you are trying to open a `csv` file, then you have only 1 worksheet, try `csvFiles.Sheets(1).Columns("20").Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r).Offset(1, 0)`

Comment: must be something with how im naming my worksheets. Yes I should have had it as Sheets(1) I agree, but nothing is happening when running this macro.